# What happens if I don't pay utility bill even after repeated customer service interaction to stop the service?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, credit, billing, utilities

It's a slightly long story. I live in an apartment building in MN (US). There was a mistake when I moved in and eventually the gas utility for the building remained in my name. Usually it is supposed to be in the landlord's name. I know, I made a grave error here. I paid my past bill, even though I wasn't supposed to.

Then, I called the gas company and told them the issue so I don't have to pay for gas in the future. They told me that, they will remove the gas service form my name and put it in landlord's name. I have called this company like a million times.

I was checking my online account with this company and found that they haven't removed it from my name. It seems I still pay for the gas service of the building instead of the landlord.

I'm getting tired of this chase and eventually decided that I will stop paying for the service. I was told that the account will be removed from my name but it hasn't been done.

What consequences am I to expect ?

Comment: Are you paying the gas service for the entire building (multiple units) instead of just one unit? Was the gas supposed to be included in the rent?

Comment: Do you want to _stop_ the service? Did you move out? Or do you want to stop _paying_ for the service only?

Comment: Try to get the landlord/owner of the apartment to contact the gas company, not you.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you agreed to have the utility in your name when you moved in, even though this was a mistake. I'm guessing you may have signed a document reflecting this.

If you simply stop paying, you can expect the service will be cut off and the bill may eventually find its way to a collection agency. You should expect to see a black mark on your credit rating. They may also take you to small claims court. This may or may not be appropriate (depending on what you signed), I'm just telling you what you should expect.

In order to deal with this, send them a written letter via registered mail. That way, you will have proof that you have dealt with the issue. Note that this may not be sufficient; for example, you may have signed up on a long-term contract when you moved in, and so are legally responsible for the debt until the contract expires. Hopefully that's not the case here, though, and hopefully this letter is sufficient. It's more likely to be successful than a telephone call, in my experience.

Comment: Even a long-term contract wouldn't result in actual gas usage here, just the (probably much) lower maintenance fee for zero therms used.